# Regex to extract specific XML tags and name them in XML file

Tags: regex, powershell

I wanted to extract values and name the variables of two XML tags (FCF and DKY tags from the below sample).
I was able to extract and name the values separately in two separate regex, but I am unable to read them together in one regex.

I am failing to get the output in one regex expression.

Sample XML:

```
 <FCF>100</FCF>
 <REF>AAAAAAAAAAAA</REF>
 <DNA></DNA>
 <DDB>1968-08-01 00:00:00</DDB>
 <DKY>00003</DKY>
 <DNT>ARE</DNT>
 <DAD>1170</DAD>
 <DCI>AE</DCI>
```

Current Powershell Script with regex:

```
switch -Regex -File $inputxml
{

'<FCF>(?<key1>[-]?\d+)</FCF>'
    {
        $currentFCF = $matches.Key1
        continue 
    }   
    
    
'<DKY>(?<key2>.*)</DKY>'
    {
        $currentDKY = $matches.Key2
        continue 
    }   
    
}
```

I am expecting to have something like this, but the below regex doesn't work

```
'<FCF>(?<Key1>[-]?\d+)</FCF>[\s\S]*<DKY>(?<Key2>.*)</DKY>'
    {
        $currentFCF = $matches.Key1
        $currentDKY = $matches.Key2
        continue 
    }
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code you've written in powershell so far?

Comment: Why would you use regex for this when it can be easily done with `XmlDocument` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that choice made due to a different problem, XML is not well formed, so I had to use the regex

Comment: How are you receiving this string? You can append tags to it an load it into an `XmlDocument` that's not a problem

Comment: updated my question with current powershell that I have @ChadBaldwin

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon there is another problem, XML file size is it too big. It can go up-to to 60GB, with XMLDOcument it takes long time to execute the script.

Comment: You do realize that, if you want to match 2 different lines of the XML that will require to have it all in memory? You should stick with that `switch`

Comment: I see, I didn't think about it. You are right. @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `switch` is perfectly fine and, if you wanted to match 2 different lines with one *regex* pattern, as far as I can tell, it would require to load all the file in memory and I don't think that's a route you want to take considering it's size is 60Gb+. You could add a new condition to your `switch` statement where it would break the loop if both variables have been populated so you don't need to keep looping until EOF:

```
switch -Regex -File $inputxml {

    { $currentFCF -and $currentDKY } { break }

    '<FCF>(?<key1>[-]?\d+)</FCF>' {
        $currentFCF = $matches.Key1
        continue
    }

    '<DKY>(?<key2>.*)</DKY>' {
        $currentDKY = $matches.Key2
        continue
    }
}
```